# C++ armadillo linear algebra library linker error with GCC

Tags: c++, linker, armadillo

I'm getting the following error with GCC >=9 and std>=11 merely by adding the header (MacOSX on MacBook Pro 2020 and armadillo installed with Homebrew and the code is compiled with standard CMake configuration)
`#include <armadillo>`
to my project.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___emutls_v._ZN4arma19mt19937_64_instanceE", referenced from:
__GLOBAL__sub_I_Test_HPP.cpp in Test_HPP.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Test_HPP] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test_HPP.dir/all] Error 2

I've tried various hacks including optimization flags e.g. O2, O3 etc. but finally adding the preprocessor header
`#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` 
apparently resolved the issue for now but I need an explanation to feel settled. If the above pre-processor is absolutely necessary to compile the code, should the armadillo library maintainers absorb the macro  within the library itself? This kind of issues may take a lot of time to resolve as it is not originated in any programming logic.

Comment: What OS is your build host ?

Comment: Configure your compiler to link with the armadillo runtime library, as explained in the README file and the Armadillo [questions page](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html). For GCC and clang, link with `-larmadillo`, like so: `g++ code.cpp -o code -O2 -larmadillo`

Comment: of course -larmadillo is used to link without which it won't link even with the WRAPPER header as described

Comment: fwiw  I think the symbol you've provided for the emulated TLS feature is not available in your copy of gcc. Possibly because it has been built without that support by your maintainer of gcc

Comment: Possible and GCC is installed using default Homebrew settings if that may imply lack of that TLS feature although I'll be highly suspicious of that. What happens when I add the wrapper ```#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER```

Comment: It looks the wrapper uses the `thread_local` feature of cpp which depends on the emulation of TLS on OSX. So when you disable the wrapper with the preprocessor define it excludes the `thread_local` code from the build. I believe the wrapper code is in [wrapper1.cpp](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/10.5.x/src/wrapper1.cpp), [wrapper2](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/10.5.x/src/wrapper2.cpp)

Comment: Wonderful research @lgflorentino ! Will give a closer look into the code but seems to be in the right direction of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor directive `ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` disables code that uses `thread_local` which depends on `emutls` in `gcc` on macOS. This appears unsupported on macOS 11 (Big Sur) according to the maintainers of Armadillo. As shown here [CMakeLists.txt](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/10.5.x/CMakeLists.txt#L102).

A related workaround is provided by the maintainers [Commit 83e48f8c](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/commit/83e48f8c6b966baebc098f32f6f988eea7b06a3a) in file `include/armadillo_bits/arma_rng.hpp`

I'm unable to confirm why it is unsupported in macOS or Homebrew but from other doc, it looks like trying a different build system configuration with correct TLS support might fix the issue e.g ugrading `gcc` or maybe rebuilding `gcc` with the `--enable-tls` switch. I'm using Catalina and my `gcc` version installed with Homebrew is `11.1.0`. If you need `gcc` version 9 you can switch between them using the `brew link <package>@<version>` command.

Comment: This a great analysis and research on the topic. I'm on Big Sur, which makes the assertions consistent